# Ajuda com um PIVOT ( Sql Server )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Galera procurei muitos exemplos de Pivot mas não consegui entender... e simplesmente não estou conseguindo utilizar no meu select... o que acontece, estou tendo esse resultado :

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  Controle     | Colonia     |    Nome    |  Matricula| QtaPessoa | Tipo Hospedagem                | NumeroVoucher | valorvoucher| Tipovoucher |
+---------------|-------------|------------|-----------|-----------|--------------------------------+---------------|-------------|-------------|
|  114539       | Campos      |   Cassio   |  1234567  | 2         | Associado a partir 12 anos     | 987654321     | 158,90      | Evento      |
|  114539       | Campos      |   Cassio   |  1234567  | 2         | Associado de 12 anos           | 123456789     | 100,00      | Promoçao    |
|  114539       | Campos      |   Cassio   |  1234567  | 3         | Associado de 7 a 11 anos       | 123456789     | 100,00      | Promoçao    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

E gostaria de ter Esse resultado

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------++-------------------------------------------+
|  Controle| Colonia| Nome |  Matricula|| Associado a partir 12 anos| Associado de 12 anos| Associado de 7 a 11 anos || NumeroVoucher | valorvoucher| Tipovoucher |
+----------|--------|------|-----------||----------------------------------------------------------------------------++---------------|-------------|-------------|
|  114539  | Campos |Cassio|  1234567  ||             2             |       NULL          |         NULL           | 987654321      | 158,90      | Evento      |
|  114539  | Campos |Cassio|  1234567  ||             NULL          |       2             |         3                  | 123456789      | 100,00      | Promoçao    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Meu select seria

```
SELECT distinct
    a.idEmpregadoReserva as Controle
    ,(select EmpresaAplicativo from tbEmpresaAplicativo where tbEmpresaAplicativo.idEmpresaAplicativo = c.idEmpresaAplicativo) Colonia
    ,d.Nome
    ,d.Matricula
    ,a.NumeroDocumento as [Numero Voucher]
    ,e.ValorVoucher
    ,f.TipoVoucher 
    ,(select tipoformapagto from tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto where tbHPG_TipoFormaPagto.idTipoFormaPagto = a.idTipoFormaPagto) [Forma Pagamento]
  FROM [APCEF].[dbo].[tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Financeiro] a join tbHPG_EmpregadoReserva_Reserva b on a.idEmpregadoReserva = b.idEmpregadoReserva
   join tbHPG_Reserva c on b.idReserva = c.idReserva join tbEmpregado d on c.idEmpregado = d.idEmpregado join tbEmpregadoVoucher e
    on a.NumeroDocumento = e.idEmpregadoVoucher
    join tbTipoVoucher f on e.idTipoVoucher = f.idTipoVoucher
  where c.DataEntrada between '2019-01-23' and '2019-01-27' and (c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 4 or c.idEmpresaAplicativo = 5) 
  and a.idTipoFormaPagto = 1
```

Tentei de varias maneiras mas como tem muito join de inumeras tabelas estou me perdendo.

Comment: É `MySQL` ou `SQL Server`? Os valores são fixos ou variáveis? Você não adicionou a estrutura das tabelas e deu poucas informações que possibilitem a resposta. Tente simplificar sua pergunta de forma que seja fácil encontrar a raiz do seu problema e propor uma solução. Da forma como sua pergunta foi feita é difícil fazer a resposta útil para outros usuários

Comment: Utilizo 'SQL SERVER', os valores são fixos,  o meu maior problema seria transformar essas linhas "tipo hospedagem" em colunas evitando que crie varias linhas por conta da Quantidade de pessoas e o tipo de hospedagem,

Basicamente seria,   1 quarto  pode ter varios tipos de hospedes e eu gostaria de deixar tudo junto a mesma hospedagem e voucher.

obs: Sorack você é o cara curto muito seu trampo em sql aqui no stack aprendi muito do 0 com vc ajudando a galera xD,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não informou corretamente qual o `SGBD` utilizado, não informou a estrutura das tabelas e não disse se os tipos variam ou se são fixos. Utilizei a estrutura a seguir para `MySQL` porém irá funcionar também para `SQL Server` considerando que os tipos sejam fixos:

```
CREATE TABLE reserva (
  controle   INTEGER,
  quantidade INTEGER,
  tipo       VARCHAR(100),
  valor      NUMERIC(15, 2),
  voucher    VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO reserva(controle, quantidade, tipo, valor, voucher) VALUES
(114539, 2, 'Associado a partir 12 anos', 158.90, 'Evento'),
(114539, 2, 'Associado de 12 anos', 100.00, 'Promoção'),
(114539, 3, 'Associado de 7 a 11 anos', 100.00, 'Promoção');
```

A query ficaria similar à seguinte:

```
SELECT r.controle,
       SUM(CASE r.tipo WHEN 'Associado a partir 12 anos' THEN r.quantidade ELSE 0 END) AS 'Associado a partir 12 anos',
       SUM(CASE r.tipo WHEN 'Associado de 12 anos' THEN r.quantidade ELSE 0 END) AS 'Associado de 12 anos',
       SUM(CASE r.tipo WHEN 'Associado de 7 a 11 anos' THEN r.quantidade ELSE 0 END) AS 'Associado de 7 a 11 anos',
       r.valor,
       r.voucher
  FROM reserva r
 GROUP BY r.controle,
          r.valor,
          r.voucher
```

Resultando em:

```
| controle | valor | voucher  | Associado a partir 12 anos | Associado de 12 anos | Associado de 7 a 11 anos |
| -------- | ----- | -------- | -------------------------- | -------------------- | ------------------------ |
| 114539   | 158.9 | Evento   | 2                          | 0                    | 0                        |
| 114539   | 100   | Promoção | 0                          | 2                    | 3                        |
```

Você deve utilizar na cláusula `GROUP BY` as colunas as quais irão agrupar o registro, no caso do resultado que você apresentou, aparentemente você só não quer agrupar o tipo (que irá se tornar uma coluna utilizando o `CASE` na `query`) e a quantidade (que irá ser somada com o `SUM`).

Você pode ver o resultado da `query` em execução no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t3XvLjLJ6ePzMVfoDpsGhe/0).

Caso queira utilizar o `PIVOT` a `query` ficaria como a seguinte:

```
SELECT y.controle,
       ISNULL(y.[Associado a partir 12 anos], 0) AS [Associado a partir 12 anos],
       ISNULL(y.[Associado de 12 anos], 0) AS [Associado de 12 anos],
       ISNULL(y.[Associado de 7 a 11 anos], 0) AS [Associado de 7 a 11 anos],
       y.valor,
       y.voucher
  FROM reserva r
 PIVOT (SUM(r.quantidade) FOR r.tipo IN ([Associado a partir 12 anos], [Associado de 12 anos], [Associado de 7 a 11 anos])) y
```

> [**Usando `PIVOT` e `UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Você pode usar os operadores relacionais `PIVOT` e `UNPIVOT` para alterar uma expressão com valor de tabela em outra tabela. `PIVOT` gira uma expressão com valor de tabela ao transformar os valores exclusivos de uma coluna na expressão em colunas múltiplas na saída, além de executar agregações onde forem necessárias em quaisquer valores de coluna remanescentes que sejam desejados na saída final. `UNPIVOT` executa a operação oposta a `PIVOT`, girando colunas de uma expressão com valor de tabela em valores de coluna.

Comment: A solução que você aplicou com a ausência das informações citadas acima, na mesma logica eu consegui solucionar utilizando CASE em vez de utilizar o PIVOT !
Muito obrigado