# Como utilizar SUM em um código de vários retornos?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, select

Fiz em um código onde faz uma somatória de dados inseridos nos meses,
porém não sei como fazer com que o `AS` transforme-se em um `array`.

O Código que fiz:

```
DECLARE @I INT = 1;
WHILE @I < 12
BEGIN 
  SELECT SUM(valueEarn) AS monthValue1
    FROM earnAccount
   INNER JOIN bankAccount ON bankAccount.idBankAccount = 1
   WHERE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) = @I

  SET @I += 1
END
```

como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver ele me retorna o mesmo nome de coluna `monthValue1`, queria que gera-se de `monthValue1` a `monthValue12`,pq depois vou pegar esses dados para colocar em um gráfico.

queria algo nesse estilo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta a estrutura das tabelas utilizada no select. e explique com mais detalhes a regra do que você precisa.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ajuda com um PIVOT ( Sql Server )](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362219/ajuda-com-um-pivot-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrá-los linha a linha basta remover o `while` e adicionar um `CASE` verificando qual o mês em questão:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 1 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue1,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 2 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue2,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 3 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue3,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 4 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue4
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 5 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue5,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 6 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue6,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 7 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue7,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 8 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue8,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 9 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue9,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 10 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue10,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 11 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue11,
       SUM(CASE MONTH(dateEarnCreate) WHEN 12 THEN valueEarn ELSE 0 END) AS monthValue12
  FROM earnAccount
 INNER JOIN bankAccount
    ON bankAccount.idBankAccount = 1
```

Comment: obrigado ajudou sim, porém no caso ali está errado em vez de THEM é THEN